# can't use different environment for puppet agent

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have an agent/master setup. I have created a new environment in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/` called `master`.

The content of `environment.conf` for the `master` directory environment is

```
modulepath = site:modules:$basemodulepath
manifest = manifests/site.pp
```

and when I try `puppet agent -t --environment master` I am getting some error

```
Notice: Local environment: 'master' doesn't match server specified node environment 'production', switching agent to 'production'.
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for node1.localpuppet.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1490712072'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.67 seconds
```

I am new to puppet. What changes do I need?

[PE Console Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUXpV.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a "really fun" quirk of Puppet Enterprise that showed up in the last couple of years. You have to specify the nodes in the PE Classifier that are allowed to specify their directory environment in the `puppet.conf` or in the `puppet agent -t --environment` arguments.

In the agent-specified environment tab in the Classifier (you see it at the bottom of your picture above), you can enable it for all nodes. Do this by adding a rule, selecting the `name` fact, using a regular expression (`~`), then using the regexp for matching all characters (`.*`). After you fill this out, the PE Classifier will give you a number of matching nodes. It should be all that are subscribed to your master. Remember to click in the bottom right to update your rules. Your nodes will now be able to use `master` instead of `production` from the config file or CLI arguments.

That being said, if you are doing this to avoid naming your default Git branch `production` in your control repository when working with Code Manager, you should really just rename the branch as that is much easier.

Comment: Alternatively, one can specify the wanted environment at the master, instead of permitting agents to name their own.  I'm not sure how exactly one does that in PE, but I suppose there's an option for it in the GUI somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard. It worked after I added the fact `name ~ .*` in the  Production environment tab.

Comment: I'm using Puppet Open Source. Can you specify how to do this without the PE Classifier?